# SharedPreferences Click Checkbox And Hiding Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two activities, `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. `ActivityA` has a Checkbox, `ActivityB` has a Button. When I click the `Checkbox` in `ActivityA`, I want the Button in `ActivityB` to be invisible. I want it to be visible when I lift the tick. And most importantly I want to save it with `SharedPreferences`. So I want to exit the program and re-enter the last process I do. Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Accpet  (click on checkmark)  my answer if its helpful for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activity_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FF5722"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:text="Show Button"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Next Screen"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity A :you can acheive using **sharedpreference**.

Step 1 :  put below code in your A activity and yes btn is used for checking next screen button is hidden or not

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits") final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        chk=findViewById(R.id.chk);
        btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);

        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    editor.putBoolean("isShow",false);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                else
                {
                    editor.putBoolean("isShow",true);
                    editor.apply();
                }


            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

activity_b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnshoworhide"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="show me or not"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Step 1 :  put below code in your B activity

```
boolean showornot;
    btnshoworhide=findViewById(R.id.btnshoworhide);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ButtonPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        showornot=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isShow",false);
        if(!showornot)
        {
            btnshoworhide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            btnshoworhide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Its Easy && **Nice** 
I run this code successfully ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But this was not exactly what I wanted;
1- Tick status does not register,
2- With this code, the button remains passive.

Comment: Status Checkbox does not register and your code does not work.

Comment: is it throw any exception ?

Comment: hey @user3286702 i updated my answer check it and its working well. and yes first time you must be perform any checkbox event

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from activity A to B by Intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, B.class);
intent.putExtra("checkbox_result", "true");
startActivity(intent);
```

And get data in B Activity and save this string in shared preference:

```
String check= getIntent().getStringExtra("checkbox_result");
```

Comment: No transition from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common sharedPreference which is accessible allover your application. put data on it from activity A and read it from activity B.

get instance of it from both activity like this.

```
SharedPreference  sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(context);
```

saved data on it,

```
SharedPreference.Editor editor = sp.getEditor();
editor.putBoolean(MY_BOL, checkboxValue).apply();
```

read saved value from same preference you used to save to, get an instance of it the same way you did while saving as shown above,
get value, do this in onCreate() method of activity N.

```
boolean bol = sharedPreference. getBoolean(MY_BOL, false);

button.setVisibility(bol);
```